# How to find the command line for tinymce

Tags: command-line

I have installed the packages `tinymce` and `tinymce2`. It's an HTML Editor.

```
sudo apt-get install tinymce tinymce2
```

but when I launch the command `tinymce` the system tells me there's no such command. Same for `tinymce2`. I have noticed that they don't seem to be in `/usr/bin/`

I have tried `man tinymce` and `man tinymce2` and the system says there's no man entry for them.

What can I do to find the command line to launch the application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tinymce is a javascript library for HTML so you need to create HTML and put it onto web browser.

The javascripts are located in /usr/share/tinymce/www, you can create link in document root of your web server.